# Tomcat NTLM Username lookup in Win7 AD environment - samba or waffle?

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-7, active-directory, ntlm

I'm writing a Java Tomcat intranet app that uses NTLM to lookup a user's name. This is in a Win7 Active Directory environment.

Is it better to use [Waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com/) or [Spnego](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Windows#Q4) for this? (Or something better?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was simple LDAP lookups using the Java libraries `javax.naming.directory.*`.

Comment: Waffle is better, as it doesn't need a password.  If you use an LDAP query there is more to configure, and you need to store the password somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Waffle has a huge following now, and will do the job well. But I am bias :)